# Need xml markup on persisting xml data to file using XmlParser

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

After updating or adding something to an xml file, the xml declaration is removed. I am using **XmlParser**. Here is the code to update something in the xml.

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(new File(fileLocation).getText('UTF-8'))
def found = xml.myTag1.findAll()
found.each{
     it.mySubTag.value="Updated"
}

XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
def nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new File(fileLocation)))
nodePrinter.preserveWhitespace=true
nodePrinter.print(xml)
```

Updating is successful btw. Only the problem is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` removed after updating.

Comment: Tried `XmlUtil.serialize(xml)`?

Comment: @tim_yates yes. updated the code still not working

Comment: @ayZagen, you mean to say that tim's suggestion worked, right?

Comment: @Rao no sorry, forgot to mention it :) updated the comment also :D

Comment: @tim_yates, sorry for hopping in.

Comment: @Rao hahaha :-D  No worries :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to achieve the same. Credits to @tim_yates. 
Just note the last line.

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(new File(fileLocation).getText('UTF-8'))
def found = xml.myTag1.findAll()
found.each{
     it.mySubTag.value="Updated"
}

//Write content of updated xml into file with xml declaration
new File(fileLocation).write(groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml))
```

If you want to write in utf-8?

```
new File(fileLocation).withWriter('UTF-8') { writer ->
    writer.write(groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml))
}
```

Comment: that worked like a charm. just out of curiosity, why it removes the first whitespace after xml declaration ? Is there any way to keep it?

Comment: Did not get you?

Comment: Not sure, but I do not see such behaviour.